# Problems with Adobe Flash Plugin in Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Tags: flash, plugins, adobe

Though the Software center is showing that "Adobe Flash Plugin" is installed in my computer, which is a Compaq Presario c700 running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, yet some websites like www.youtube.com is prompting me to download Adobe Flash Plugin to view online streaming.
PS: I have the latest version of Adobe Flash Plugin

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Please include the output of `dpkg -l \*flash\*` run from a terminal and include what browser you're using. Do this by *editing* your question.

Comment: you might want to avoid flash atleast for youtube by enabling HTML5 mode in youtube.

Answer (score 7):

I ran into the same issue. dpkg showed that flashplugin-installer was already installed but no flash in Firefox. I resolved it by running

```
sudo apt-get --reinstall install flashplugin-installer
```

Answer (score 4):

After encountering a problem with adobe flash player not being clickable on cam chat sites I became very aggravated..and it takes that for me to fix stuff I guess.

Remove Flash player plugin from within firefox [is what I use]
use:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get autoremove then,
```

use terminal to re-install flash plugin:

```
sudo apt-get install flashplugin-installer
```

After doing the exact above actions the adobe flash player problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue before, on another computer, and after trying countless different ways to fix it (including completely removing and installing `flashplugin-installer`, `adobe-flashplugin`, the version from adobe's website, pepper flash, etc...), I finally fixed it by using an older version of flash.

I basically went here: http://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/kb/archived-flash-player-versions.html, then I [downloaded 11.1](http://fpdownload.macromedia.com/get/flashplayer/installers/archive/fp_11.1.102.63_archive.zip) (no real reason why, it's just because I didn't want to try each version, so I decided that it would be better to have a version too old, than to have to download test each one).

I installed `flashplugin-installer` again, then I extracted the archive, went to `fp_11.1.102.63_archive` -> `11_1r102_63_32bit` (change `32bit` to `64bit` if your system is 64-bit), extracted `flashplayer11_1r102_63_linux.i386.tar.gz` (replace `i386` to `x86_64` if you system is 64-bit), and then copied `libflashplayer.so` to `/usr/lib/flashplugin-installer/`.

After I had restarted chromium, everything worked fine! This should work for firefox too.

There is a [copy-and-paste instruction](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1953796&page=11&p=12362874#post12362874) on how to do this.